# How do I avoid duplicate queries in Django admin for a get_queryset() overwrite in a ModelAdmin page

Tags: mysql, django

I overwrote `get_queryset` and get the results I require. The problem is however that the page takes quite long to load. Upon checking the `SQL debugger`, it became apparent that two the same queries are executed and a third similar query. Does anyone have a reason why and how this could be avoided?

Thank you kindly in advance.

SQL:

````
QUERY   TIMELINE    TIME (MS)   ACTION
+   
SELECT ••• FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '''2021-07-13 20:49:27.015683''' AND "django_session"."session_key" = '''26huoisce3p4p3ef0f37vysjzo55uu3h''') LIMIT 21
1.18    
Sel Expl
+   
SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = '1' LIMIT 21
0.58    
Sel Expl
+   
SELECT ••• FROM "inventory_product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bolData_invoice_line" ON ("inventory_product"."id" = "bolData_invoice_line"."product_id") GROUP BY "inventory_product"."id") subquery
 2 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.        1625.29 
Sel Expl
+   
SELECT ••• FROM "inventory_product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bolData_invoice_line" ON ("inventory_product"."id" = "bolData_invoice_line"."product_id") GROUP BY "inventory_product"."id") subquery
 2 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.        1449.67 
Sel Expl
+   
SELECT ••• FROM "inventory_product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bolData_invoice_line" ON ("inventory_product"."id" = "bolData_invoice_line"."product_id") GROUP BY "inventory_product"."id", "inventory_product"."ean", "inventory_product"."hscode_id" ORDER BY "return_rate" DESC, "inventory_product"."id" DESC LIMIT 100
1387.94 
Sel Expl``` 

PYTHON/DJANGO:

```@admin.register(ProductProxy)
class ProductProxyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ProductProxyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(
                  total_sales=Coalesce(Sum('invoice_line__invoiced_quantity',
                          filter=Q(invoice_line__invoice_linetype__id=3)),0.0),
                  total_returns=Coalesce(Sum('invoice_line__invoiced_quantity',
                          filter=Q(invoice_line__invoice_linetype__id=7)), 0.0)) \
                .annotate(
                  return_rate=ExpressionWrapper(F('total_returns')* 1.0 /F('total_sales'),
                           output_field=DecimalField(decimal_places=2))
                ).order_by('-return_rate')
        return qs```
````